# vite vue build doesn't pack assets which are overriden by javascript

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have the following script:

```
const stages_backdrop_A = document.getElementById("stages_backdrop_A");
stages_backdrop_A.style["background-image"] = "url('/src/assets/sascha-duensing-182.jpg')"
```

it overrides background image and works well with `quasar dev` (works well locally)

but when I do `quasar build` and `quasar serve dist/spa`, it doesn't include that asset in the final build, giving error `404 on /src/assets/sascha-duensing-182.jpg`

What can I do about it? Thank you

Comment: It's not guaranteed to work at all, either in dev. Either import the image or place it to public folder instead of src

Comment: thanks a lot Estus Flask, public folder is what I needed!